# Solution for 'Print to PDF button' with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

I will be happy if some body help me to get solution for my problem.

I have HTML5 + CSS page i need grab some main DIV and save it in PDF
i tied jsPDF library but it not rendering CSS and have some bugs in Mozilla =(

I found great API what rendering everything and send .PDF file but this project working only off-line and that should be local library.

I already create `@print` properties to my page and it printing perfectly! But my client want to see 'Save to PDF' button without any other 'dialog boxes'.  Does somebody know a solution to silence print(i saw that working only for IE) or another library to render my HTML with CSS.

Thank u!

Comment: Don't most browsers already have a Save to PDF option in the Print dialog? Creating a PDF from HTML & CSS is not a trivial process. You could try [Dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) or [Prince PDF](http://www.princexml.com/).

Comment: I need something like: hit 'Print to PDF' button and get 'save' dialog box or auto save by name, anyway thanks

Comment: Take a look at http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf, uses an external rendering engine to format to PDF via Javascript.

Comment: Yeah it working well, but it is external API my project local ;-)